# Find average from dictionary values, excluding input key

Tags: python

Using the following dictionary, create a program that takes an argument (subject) and prints the average score excluding that subject, to two decimals.

*grades = {'Biology':80, 'Physics':88, 'Chemistry':98, 'Math':89, 'English':79, 'Music':67, 'History':68, 'Art':53, 'Economics':95, 'Psychology':88}*

For example:

- If the argument is Biology, it should print 80.56
- If the argument is Chemistry, it should print 78.56

Below what I've tried so far:

```
import sys

grades = {'Biology':80, 'Physics':88, 'Chemistry':98, 'Math':89, 'English':79, 'Music':67, 'History':68, 'Art':53, 'Economics':95, 'Psychology':88}

def average_grade():
    key = sys.argv[1]
    included_keys = grades.pop(key)

    average = sum(included_keys)/len(included_keys)
    return round(average, 2)

average_grade()
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work.  I just deleted the specific subject from the dictionary with a `del` statement, then I get all the values with `grades.values()` and I get the number of grades left with `len(grades)`.

```
import sys

grades = {'Biology':80, 'Physics':88, 'Chemistry':98, 'Math':89, 'English':79, 'Music':67, 'History':68, 'Art':53, 'Economics':95, 'Psychology':88}

def average_grade():
    key = sys.argv[1]
    del grades[key]
    average = sum(grades.values())/len(grades)
    return round(average, 2)

print(average_grade())
```

- `py file.py Biology`  it outputs `80.56`
- `py file.py Chemistry` it outputs `78.56`

Of course it would be best to use some sort of error checking as well.

For example:

```
def average_grade():
    key = sys.argv[1]
    if key not in grades:
        return "Subject does not exist. Please try again."
    del grades[key]
    average = sum(grades.values())/len(grades)
    return round(average, 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(average_grade())
```

Now if I enter `py file.py German` it outputs `Subject does not exist. Please try again.`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a copy of the dictionary, so the original dictionary will remain the same.

```
grades = {'Biology':80, 'Physics':88, 'Chemistry':98, 'Math':89, 'English':79, 'Music':67, 'History':68, 'Art':53, 'Economics':95, 'Psychology':88}

def average_grade(key):
    g = grades.copy()
    try:
        g.pop(key)
    except KeyError:
        print('Subject not exixts')
        return None

    average = sum(g)/len(g)
    return round(average, 2)

print(average_grade())
```

> In your code `included_keys = grades.pop(key)` will return a number
> not a list and the calculation goes wrong here `average = sum(included_keys)/len(included_keys)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator expression to skip the unwanted key, and `statistics.mean` to calculate the mean.

```
from statistics import mean

def average_grade(grades, exclude):
    if exclude in grades:
        return mean(v for k, v in grades.items() 
            if k != exclude)
    raise KeyError(f'Subject "{exclude}" not found')

average = average_grade(grades, sys.argv[1])
print(f"{average:.2f}")
```

Comment: How about sum and subtract the corresponding value: `(sum(grades.values()) - grades[k])`?

Comment: @MechanicPig yes that also works